# If textfield is empty set border to red, if we enter text, remove red border

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ipad, border

In Swift, I have added border color red to text fields. I want to implement that if we enter any text in it, the textfield border color should be removed, and if again there is no text in it, the border color should again be set to red. Without a click of any button.
(programmatically only)

Comment: You can add a target for editingChanged and do whatever you need using the method called

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do this with following simple code.
add this below line in you viewdidload or view configure method

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

change your text field border color or remove the border as you need

```
@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if (textField.text!.isEmpty)
        {
            // change your textfield border color
        }
        else
        {
            // remove text field border or change color
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can simply use `if textField.hasText {` and `#selector(textFieldDidChange)`

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
if self.yourTextField.text.isEmpty
{
   self.yourTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
   self.yourTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1
}
else
{
   self.yourTextField.layer.borderWidth = 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 14 / Swift 5.7:

Setup a binding variable and use the .onChange modifier with an .overlay modifier containing a shape (i.e. RoundedRectangle) to change the "border" color. NOTE: you will want to use the .textFieldStyle(PlainTextField()) modifier too.

```
@State private var isTitleMissing: Bool = true
@State private var inputTitle: String = ""
            
TextField("Insert Title", text: $inputTitle)
    .textFieldStyle(PlainTtextFieldStyle())
    .onChange(of: inputTitle) { _ in
        isTitleMissing = inputTitle.isEmpty
    }
    .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16).stroke(isTitleMissing ? Color.red : Color.gray))
```